# Communicate to another, specific controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I'm a bit lost... I'm quite new to Angular and writing a small app for practicing.

I've two views with a table and each view has it's own controller. The tables use some equal functions, like edit, save... To avoid duplicate code I've put these functions in a seperate controller. Now if in one view e.g. the data in a table-row is edited and saved I want to fire an event to inform the specific controller for that view and send the new object with that event. I already got that running but not sure if it is the right way to do it...

So right now my TableEditController is parent of each table-view-specific Controller and I can send the event with `$emit`. By doing some research I've read, that you should use a service for the communication, but in the examples $rootScope is used and I think that's not the right way to do it, as I only want to inform the specific controller about the change so that it can do further handling (like saving to database or whatever).

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Try using a service rather than a controller, to control similar functions.

Comment: @ThorJacobsen Yes, that's what I plan to do. But I'm not sure how to broadcast or emit only to that specific controller that's concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your business logic in a `service` and share the `service` with you `controllers` to **avoid** code duplication.

If you have the same `controller` methods as well (and a lot of them) , then create a `parent controller` (or inherit via `prototype`) with the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to controllers communicate, you show create parent controller as below

```
<div ng-controller="parent_controller">
   <div ng-controller="child_controller_1"></div>
   <div ng-controller="child_controller_2"></div>
</div>
```

child_controller_1 and child_controller_2 will communicate via parent_controller.